# Beckhoff CX9020 - Can't establish a connection with TwinCAT 3

Tags: codesys, twincat

I've got a **Beckhoff CX9020** module with the following informations (as seen in *General* Tab in the *CX Configuration Tool*):

System Information:

- Device Name: **CX-xxxxxx**
- Image Version: **CX9020 HPS 5.02d**
- CXConfig Version: **1.0 (Build 73)**
- CPU Frequency: **1000 MHz**

TwinCAT:

- Version: **2.11**
- TC Build: **2254**
- AMS Net Id: **5.39.55.247.1.1**
- Reg Level: **PLC**

Now I have installed TwinCAT 3, but **can't establish a working Connection**.

The questions:

- Is it, because there is a wrong Image installed on the *Win 7 Compact Embedded* CX9020?
- If that is the case, how can I install a newer TwinCAT 3 Image?

Comment: What kind of connection are you trying to establish? Remote desktop? TwinCAT ADS?

Comment: It's an ADS connection. I got it running by using a trial version of the old TwinCAT 2.1. BUt it would be nice to have TwinCAT 3 (e.g. for C++ support).

Comment: You can't connect to a TwinCat 2 PLC using TwinCat 3. I've also had a CX9xxx and Beckhoff told me it was impossible to upgrade it to TwinCat3. I'm now using a CX5000 using TwinCat3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to establish route to the controller.
General idea is to right-click "TwinCAT" icon in the tray, select "router" and then "edit routes". Then add your controller by IP or by searching.

Assuming you use C# for your application:
You should use Twincat.Ads command `yourClient.Connect(5.39.55.247.1.1,851)`
Where the address is of the controller with ".1.1" and the port is the ADS port.
To get the port you should double click the controller in the PLC part of the project and look at the port there. Default of first PLC is 851.

When you have `using TwinCAT.Ads;`
just add

```
tcClient = new TcAdsClient();
tcClient.Connect(5.39.55.247.1.1,851);
```

to the code.

You can find good examples on the Beckhoff site for C# and for other languages.